# Raster calculator - negative value return Nodata

Tags: arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, rusle

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.7.0

I am trying to explain what exactly is my problem.

I have an Aspect raster. I had to calculate sin(Aspect) and cos(Aspect), so I have converted the Aspect to radians, and then calculated the sin and cos of Aspect raster (in radians).

I then calculated Sin(Aspect) + Cos(Aspect) (1) ((both values in the radians)). So far, everything ok.

The above equation (1), returned me a raster(Y) ranging from 1.414 to -1.414 (values are in the correct range, as I have tested it with a calculator)

Then, when I tried to rise to power the above raster (Y), to a power of a coefficient (values ranging from 0 to 0.73), all cells where the raster Y had negative values, were returned as NoData.

I checked with a calculator, and for example, for cell x: I have a raster Y value of: -1.393 and a raster coefficient value of: 0.38

If I rise to power -1.393 ^ 0.38, it should be = - 1.134

In my case, raster calculator has returned NoData. And this applies to every cell where I have a negative values for raster Y. Only positive values in raster Y returned the correct result.

Why? Or maybe someone has already calculated this and can give me some directions (it's my first time ever doing this)

PS: maybe someone is more familiar with what I am trying to calculate, it is the L factor of the RUSLE model, applying the equation from Desmet and Govers, (1996)

I have attached a screenshot of the paper I am trying to follow, so you can see better in more details.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747124/valueerror-negative-number-cannot-be-raised-to-a-fractional-power) might be the issue?

Comment: (-1.393)**0.38 is a complex number 0.417+1.054i  and most certainly aspect plays no role in this erosion model